# html "delivery method" list with images and text

Tags: html, css

Im not a coder, i am trying to make a website on my own, and everything is going ok but for one current problem (which i am sure is very easy, its just that i am a newb). So, what i have in mind is making a list with description of delivery methods i use. On left row i want to place delivery companies logo, next to it write method (courier/post office), and on the right text (price or stuff like that).
Example in image [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uvIQ.png)
Tags like "li" "div ul li" "img" and "div ul li img" are already in use, so i have to make special tag for every new entry/list.
Can someone recommend me on how to do it? Right now im on this:

[HTML]

```
<div>
        <img src="images/delivery_menu.jpg" alt="">

    <ul>
        <li class="Delivery_mety">
                <img src="images/omniva.jpg" alt="">
                <span class="Delivery_mety">Omniva pakiautomaat</span>
        </li>
      <li class="Delivery_mety">
                <img src="images/omniva.jpg" alt="">
                <span class="Delivery_mety">Omniva postkontor</span>
        </li>
        <li class="Delivery_mety">
                <img src="images/itella.jpg" alt="">
                <span class="Delivery_mety">Itella smartpost</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

[CSS]

```
.Delivery_mety {
font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right:50%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
align-content:center;
}
```

And still all is [wrongly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2we3.jpg)(image incl)

Comment: It's a bit hard to read your question in its current form. Can you try shortening the first paragraph, or splitting it into smaller sections?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make every image as Link then you should write be for the img tag  `<a href=" default.asp"></a>`
and between the double quotation write the web page.

See [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)
for example:

Comment: No, actually i want to make image just based on the fact that people will recognize the logos, that's it.